# Overriding Loading Resources in WebView

Tags: android, webview, overriding, android-webview

I have a zip file containing `html files` and `images`, how can I link `images` with the `loaded html` in `WebView` without extracting the zip file to a file, the zip file is loaded into the RAM, and I have access to the images data as `byte[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how i can link images with the html loaded in WebView without extracting the zip file to SD-Card

Option #1: Extract the ZIP file to internal storage and use `file://` URLs pointing to your files

Option #2: Extract the ZIP file to internal storage, create a `ContentProvider` to publish those files, and use `content://` URLs pointing to your provider

> the zip file is loaded into the RAM

That will only be practical for small ZIP files.

Comment: the problem is am trying to make epub reader, so i dont need to extract the content to the memory, i appreciate your reply , thanks commonsWare

Comment: i think this is the best way i can do.